# undefined local variable or method `acts_as_nested_set'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am currently using Rails 4.2.5 for my project. In my gemfile, the way I install is :
gem 'awesome_nested_set'

Even though I install successfully, the problem is happened in the server. 
Error: 
undefined local variable or method `acts_as_nested_set'

only at production environment.

```html
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.5'


# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2', '0.3.18'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes

# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
#gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'awesome_nested_set', '3.0.2'


gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

gem 'devise'

gem 'rails_admin'


gem 'rb-readline'
gem 'unicorn'

gem 'capistrano', '>= 3'
gem 'capistrano-bundler'
gem 'capistrano-rbenv', github: "capistrano/rbenv"
gem 'capistrano-rails'

gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'

gem 'omniauth-oauth2', '~> 1.3.1'
# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'
gem 'wicked'
gem 'kaminari'
gem "simple_calendar", "~> 2.0"
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'chosen-rails'
gem 'mailboxer'
gem 'webpay'
gem 'unicorn'
gem 'gretel'
gem 'sitemap_generator'
gem 'stripe'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'rmagick'
gem 'i18n_generators'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'pry-rails'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  # gem 'spring'

end
```

[]# bundle show 'awesome_nested_set'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/awesome_nested_set-3.1.1

It's in there..!

Comment: It's better to update your question instead of using comment.

Comment: Did you run `bundle install` in your production environment too?

Comment: paste contents of `Gemfile`

Comment: @spickermann I did bundle install